# How to pattern match (regex/sed/awk) for an IPv4 address, and then insert a new line/carriage return *before* the IP address

Tags: regex, awk, sed, ipv4

What would be the proper way to pattern match (using: regex/sed/awk) for an IPv4 address, and then insert a new line/carriage return *before* the IP address, while also removing the comma (,) and blank space ( ) just before the IP address (if a comma and blank space are present)?

As an example, this is the type of data that I have to work with:

```
1.2.3.4 - BlahA, BlahB, BlahC, 10.11.12.13 - BlahD, BlahE, BlahF, 250.251.252.253 - BlahG, BlahH, BlahI
```

And this is how I want the output to look after the regex/sed/awk:

```
1.2.3.4 - BlahA, BlahB, BlahC
10.11.12.13 - BlahD, BlahE, BlahF
250.251.252.253 - BlahG, BlahH, BlahI
```

Comment: Why not just split on `,\s*(?=[\d\.]+)` using perl?

Comment: On SO we encourage users to put their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems, so kindly do add so in your post and let us know then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a capture group and insert a newline before each IP. Something like:

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+){3})
```

https://regex101.com/r/Kc5tCO/1

Also in your limited example (as ctwheels points out), you can split on a `,` preceding a digit, such as:

```
\, (?=\d)
```

https://regex101.com/r/Kc5tCO/2

Comment: fyi: cli tools like sed/awk don't support `\d` or lookarounds or non-capturing groups, etc

Comment: Thanks, guys!  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo '1.2.3.4 - BlahA, BlahB, BlahC, 10.11.12.13 - BlahD, BlahE, BlahF, 250.251.252.253 - BlahG, BlahH, BlahI' | sed -r 's/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]/\n&/g ; s/, *$//g'

1.2.3.4 - BlahA, BlahB, BlahC, 
10.11.12.13 - BlahD, BlahE, BlahF, 
250.251.252.253 - BlahG, BlahH, BlahI
```

The first sed command inserts a newline before every IP address.  The second sed command deletes comma followed by optional spaces at the end of each line.